# Easiest way to check if Tailwind is installed

Tags: tailwind-css

I am playing around with Tailwind and `Next.js,` but I am having trouble figuring out if it's installed or not. Even when I go to https://play.tailwindcss.com/ and try the following HTML element styled with Tailwind.

```
<h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
</h1>
```

It doesn't render it underlined or even an `h1` element. I follow the instructions at  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs verbatim. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason it's not working for you is that you are using `className` instead of `class`.

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
</h1>
```

Using NPM, you can see if a specific package is installed.

```
npm view tailwindcss version
```

Or

```
npm info tailwindcss version
```

If you're using NPX, you can do the following.

```
npx gvi tailwindcss
```

Comment: `className` is used in react, but in real HTML, it's just `class`.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, but you were testing it out on play.tailwindcss.com as well.